# OpenID Connect Hybrid flow for authentication only

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect

I have a mobile app and I want to use OpenId Connect to authenticate users against an external auth provider. I only need the `id_token` to get the users' email address, I don't need an access token (at least for now).

Are there any vulnerabilities of using a hybrid flow where I do the first request on the front channel and I set `response type = code id_token`?
If/when I'm going to use an access token, I plan to send the code to a backend to do the exchange for an access token. I'm just not sure if there are any vulnerabilities to retrieving the `id_token` on the front channel.

Answer (score 1):

The standard flow for mobile apps should be to redirect with response_type=code as in step 8 of [my write up](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/29/basicandroidapp-execution/).

You then get only an authorization code and perform an authorization code grant message to get tokens. Whether you  get an access token should be configurable in the Client entry in the Authorization Server.

You should use PKCE parameters so that no-one can get tokens if they happen to intercept the authorization code.

In the event that you can't prevent an access token from being returned you can just discard it from memory.